# TFS plugin to view builds like Build View in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs, azure-devops

I am new to Microsoft's Team Foundation Server. Have used Jenkins, but now I'm trying to explore and possibly switch to TFS. The Build View add-on in Jenkins is very helpful by providing visual view of all the deploys. Is there any in TFS that will provide information, which builds have succeeded or failed and progress of current deployments?

Thanks

Comment: You have to create release definitions in order to view release status. Builds and releases are separate entities.

Comment: There are also dashboard widgets that will give you higher level status and the ability to create some custom views.

Answer (score -1):

There is the build summary view in TFS and can review each build of a build definition.

[image]

A related article: [Visual Studio Team Services – NEW FEATURES: 3 Build Summary Page Improvements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/user_ed/2016/02/02/visual-studio-team-services-new-features-3-build-summary-page-improvements-richer-visualizations-view-passed-test-results-file-bug-on-test-failures/)